# useState with a google maps object not behaving as expected

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, use-state

I'm attempting to work with GoogleMapReact in a gatsby app and have run across a strange issue where I can't set state if the state is a Google Maps object...

```
import React, { useStat1e, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
const [ mapsObj, setMapsObj ] = useState(false)

const Map = () => {
    const [ mapsObj, setMapsObj ] = useState(false)

    const apiIsLoaded = (map, maps, places) => {
        console.log('maps', maps)
        setMapsObj(maps)
        console.log(mapsObj)
    }
}

...
```

Console responses:

```
maps {Animation: {…}, ControlPosition: {…}, __gjsload__: ƒ, BicyclingLayer: ƒ, Circle: ƒ, …}
null
```

If maps if set, why is `setMapsObj` not updating its state?

Comment: React state updates are asynchronously processed. The update you enqueued won't be available until the ***next*** render cycle. The console log of state can, and will, only ever log the state value from the ***current*** render cycle.

Comment: The maps object is correctly set, you're just [logging at the wrong time](https://jsramblings.com/are-you-logging-the-state-immediately-after-updating-it-heres-why-that-doesnt-work/) - move the `console.log` right before the `return` statement and you'll see the right value :)